# Removal of watermark ('draft')

Tags: watermark, draftwatermark

I have the watermark 'draft' on all pages in my dissertation (see below), but I'm not using the `watermark` package! (I've previously used it, but have removed it from my preamble). It's not so easy to make a MWE - or systematically remove the loading of various packages since my dissertation gets all sorts of error messages when I attempt to remove them.

Below, I've listed the packages that I load in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,fontsize=12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{tocvsec2} 
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[page,title,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{Layout}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fixme}
```

- could any of these be the reason to the watermark 'draft'?

[image]

Comment: Package `background` I assume

Comment: You are overwriting some of KOMA's functionality. You don't need to load **color**. Don't specify `pdftex` for the class or packages. Are you using all of those packages? Do you know why you are loading them? Do you understand how they do or don't interact with KOMA's functionality?

Comment: You are obviously missing the `everything-but-the-kitchen-sink` package. Seriously: Show us an MWE.

Answer (score 13):

Remove the package `background` or use

```
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
```

to remove the default content 'Draft' (default setting in `background` package.)

Some notes on the used packages

- `hyperref` is one the packages that should be loaded at the end of the preamble, not somewhere in between. (Only few exceptions from this rule do exist: `glossaries` and `cleveref` should be loaded **after** `hyperref`)
- `epsfig` is outdated
- `subfigure` is outdated -- use `subfig` instead!
- `fancyhdr` and a KOMA class like `scrbook` do not behave well with each other.

---

```
\documentclass[pdftex,fontsize=12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{tocvsec2} 
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{epsfig} % No -- outdated
%\usepackage{subfigure} % no -- outdated
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{natbib} % Does not compile
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Why?????
\usepackage[page,title,header]{appendix}
%\usepackage{Layout}  % Unknown
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fixme}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\backgroundsetup{color=black,scale=3,contents={This is another content you don't want to see}}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there any reaseon not to use draftwatermark? Should I prefere background instead of draftwatermark?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger: I don't understand your question. `draftwatermark` is not included here at all.

Comment: You are right. I am using the package and during your answer I was thinking about, if I use a outdated solution to provide watermarks or if I use a silly solution to have watermarks...using the draftwatermark package....

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger: No, I mentioned the other outdated packages like `subfigure` and `epsfig`. `draftwatermark` seems alright (I rarely used it however). `background` has a little problem: As far as I know, it does not allow more than one `\includegraphics` statement (i.e. inclusion of different background images seems to be a problem)

Comment: Compiling the answer (code) you provided, gives me an 'undefined control sequence'. Could you verify that the provided code gives you the "correct" answer, i.e. the page you attached?

Comment: @Stefan: There was in fact a `}` missing at the `subfig` package inclusion, but after fixing that, the code runs without issue

Comment: May be https://i.stack.imgur.com/du08n.png is not available at the moment. The image is not rendered.

Comment: @pushpen.paul: Well, what should I do about that? The image is there and I see it

Answer (score 0):

With the answer (code) from @ChristianHupfer I obtain:

[image]

- does this mean that the 'draft' watermark is due to some more general settings that overwrite my preamble somehow? I'll try to recompile on another laptop...
  Update: on another laptop I get the results as @ChristianHupfer. That probably means that I have to look for the solution in my WinEdt editor or MikTeX installation?

Comment: Well, this is exactly the reason why I don't use such editors as WinEdt etc. which have 'hidden' configuration options

Comment: Not MikTeX. No idea about WinEdt. But MikTeX won't be responsible.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I've been quite busy. I'll return with an update shortly